# Hidden Markov Models in games

Tags: java, hidden-markov-models

Ok i am relative new to the HMM concept here.

What i currently know is that for an unknown model with a specified number of states (N), a specified number of observation symbols (M) and a given observation sequence (O), we can find a model that maximized the probability of O.

With this i have created a HMM that utilizes the code from this document http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~stamp/RUA/HMM.pdf -> Section 7 pseudocode

The initial values of A B and pi are about 1/N and 1/M. I used matlab to generate figures so that the figures are not exact but similar.

Now lets say O's length is 1000 and i feed that into the HMM based on the pseudocode. The endstate is that i get a model of A , B and pi that adjusts itself to fit O. Am i proceeding correctly thus far?

If so, the next thing i would want to do is find the future possible observation 1001 (o1001).

With my flaky understanding of HMMs, what i need to do is from what i have at the end, take the most possible state at the moment (Taken from A after learning 1000 observations) and find which is the most probable observation from it (By looking at B matrix's row on the state that comes from A)

I am not too sure about the last portion on how to go about predicting the 1001th observation. Could someone let me know if i am on the right track thus far?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after playing around abit and finally understanding slightly more  my findings are as such.

What i previously mentioned was wrong. In order to find the next possible observation i.e 1001
i need to do the following to find p(O[1001] = k | O(1..1000)) which basically means find the probability of the observation given the previous 1000 observations which is the summation of Bi(O(1000) = K) * summation of Aji*alpha1000(j).